# How can I prevent an animated image from being shown and then hidden by the animation trigger?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I was trying to add some animations in my website using CSS and JavaScript, but I'm running into some graphical issues.

This is my code so far:

- **index.html**

```
<div class="menu__images animated-right">
    <img src="/static/images/menu.jpg" alt="Menu">
</div>
```

- **style.css**

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromLeft {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromRight {
    from {
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fade-right {
    animation: fadeInFromRight 1s ease;
}
```

- **script.js**

```
let sectionsFromRight = document.querySelectorAll('.animated-right');

window.onscroll = () => {
  sectionsFromRight.forEach(sec => {
    let top = window.scrollY + 500;
    let offset = sec.offsetTop;
    let height = sec.offsetHeight;

    if (top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
      sec.classList.add('fade-right');
    }
  })
}
```

As for the animation, everything works perfectly and it is triggered on reaching with the scroll.

But the problem is that as soon as I reach the element on the page, it's already loaded, disappears, then reappears during the animation.

I've tried everything, add/remove opacity, make the element visible/invisible, give it a translateX(100%), but nothing at all.

I can't figure out how to fix this graphical "bug".

I've recently undertaken an in-depth study of web animations and I'm not that practical yet :)

I would appreciate some help from someone if possible, so that I too understand how to approach the problem in the future.

Thanks in advance for any answer that can help me ;)

Comment: You need to give the image an initial styling of `opacity: 0;` this way it is not visible when the animation starts. You might also wanna add an `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so your image stays in place after the animation has ended.